# How to create a subfolders for each items when having a database?

Tags: php, asp.net, ruby

I was a hard time giving this a title as I am not sure what this is called. Anyhow, my question is how can do folders for each item when a have a database. Take this site as an example, whenever you click on a question it takes you to a new page with the following format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/some_id_number/question_title

I originally thought the way to go about this is to programmatically create a folder and a file (the page for this particular new item, a .php page per se) on the insertion of a new item on my table and then inside my PHP page require the page to filled out with the info retrieved.

Help pointing me in the right direction, as well as comments.

Comment: I down voted for your question. Caz' before asking anything (even if your thinking way is not correct), you have to try to do anything at least. And also you have to think about your question. Do you really think that *stackoverflow* creates a special folder and file for each question?! In this case, *stackoverflow* contains millions of pages, it is madness. They just use routing. Google routing and you will see, how they do that.

Comment: What do you want me to try creating a million folders as you said? I have asked questions here before and have answered, it is not like I don't try. But hey Genius, some us sometimes don't have a clue of where to start. Also, I am sorry for asking such a trivial question. I bet the vast majority of the users on this site know how to do what I asked.

Comment: ASP.NET routing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx 
PHP Clean URLs: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/

Answer (score 2):

Actually when you see a url like this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003332/how-to-create-a-subfolders-for-each-items-when-having-a-database` it's simply a get request! Like

```
stack.com/question.php?id=3500000332&title=how-to-create-a-subfolders-for-each...
```

So if youre confusing folders with get requests this is the answer!

Oh and to make these get requests look pretty you have to use .htaccess files

Comment: Cool thanks, I still have questions but let me do some reading about this, because I have no clue where to even start looking!

Comment: Yes search php get variables and you will get the concepts! Cheers!

Comment: Oh I know about the GET variables, I think what I have to look into is .htaccess I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a RESTful API. There's many ways to do this in PHP. Like [this](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/) for example. I recommend getting familiar with the concept of a RESTful API, [Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/REST-training-tutorials/1717-0.html) has a pretty good tutorial. If you're willing to change the language you are using, Node.js + Express makes creating REST API's very easy

Comment: Thanks, all your help is appreciated and gave the direction to go to!